# Jetty/winstone connector configuration in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jetty, winstone

I am experiencing slow download times over WAN links from JENKINS. Not going into details of the problem i would like to configure Jetty apparently used by Jenkins to add the following connector:

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
 <Set name="host"><Property name="application-host"/></Set>
 <Set name="port"><Property name="application-port"/></Set>
 <Set name="forwarded">true</Set>
 <Set name="responseBufferSize">16777216</Set>
 <Set name="responseHeaderSize">1048576</Set>
</New>
```

but i am not sure what is the right spot to do it. 
I cannot find jetty.xml file anywhere in my installation. 
I am using Jenkins on Windows so i guess i am just launching it using java -jar jenkins.war which is supposed to use Jetty/Winstone.

EDIT: Looks like this cannot be done by just changing configuration. At least not in SSL context: https://github.com/J-cztery/winstone/blob/master/src/java/winstone/HttpsConnectorFactory.java hardcodes creation of ServerContext.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use a custom servlet container like Tomcat, then Jenkins uses a built-in "Jetty/Winstone" container indeed. To be more precise: **Jenkins uses a wrapper around Jetty that implements the Winstone command line interface** (motivation was to switch from the old Winstone to Jetty without changing the interface).

The Jetty container can be customized by **adding options directly on the Jenkins command line** (that is, in your Windows case, by adding them to the `<arguments>` tag in the `jenkins.xml` file.

The **available options** (like, `--httpPort` or `--sessionTimeout`) are documented in the [Jenkins winstone repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone) on github.

**If those options are not sufficient**, then you might be able to further customize the container by modifying this section in `pom.xml`:

```
      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <port>${port}</port>
        </connector>
      </connectors>
```

...or by editing the `web.xml` file. At least the latter can be modified without changing the `war` file by editing the unpacked `$JENKINS_HOME/war/WEB-INF/web.xml`. I didn't try either yet, though.