# Jenkins standalone implementation: Winstone or Jetty?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, webserver, jetty, winstone

I am currently using the Jenkins cookbook from Chef Supermarket to manage my Jenkins configurations. I am installing via the WAR file installation option as oppose to package based installation.

I am not running Jenkins within Tomcat, but rather in Jenkins's standalone implementation. I am currently using Jenkins version 2.46.3.

My questions are:

1. Is my standalone Jenkins implementation using Winstone or Jetty?
2. How do I as a Jenkins user verify that the Jenkins instance is using
   either one of these?
3. Is there a version available to check from command line for either
   Winstone or Jetty?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just to clairfy for those who may come across this question: "If you don't use a custom servlet container like Tomcat, then Jenkins uses a built-in "Jetty/Winstone" container indeed. To be more precise: Jenkins uses a wrapper around Jetty that implements the Winstone command line interface (motivation was to switch from the old Winstone to Jetty without changing the interface)." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929964/jetty-winstone-connector-configuration-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in order to discern wether Winstone or Jetty is in use, a simple and easy way to tell is to modify the jenkins URL to point to a location that does not exist.

For example:

```
123.456.7.890:8080
```

Would be modified like this:

```
123.456.7.890:8080/chucknorris
```

As long as the modified URL is invalid, you should see along the bottom of the page something similar to the following:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /chucknorris. Reason:

    Not Found

Powered by Jetty://
```